# Can't authenticate to PyMongo database

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Here is the code I'm using to try to authenticate:

```
# MongoDB connection
connection = Connection(f.config['MONGODB_HOST'], f.config['MONGODB_PORT'])
db = connection['MONGODB_DB']

# Try authenticating. This will only work in production. In development,
# MONGODB_USER and MONGODB_PASSWORD will raise KeyErrors.
try:
    db.authenticate(f.config['MONGODB_USER'], f.config['MONGODB_PASSWORD'])
except KeyError:
    f.logger.debug('KeyError: Not authenticating.')

# Temporary. This is just for testing purposes.
users = db.users 
user = users.find_one({'username': 'BrewerOnRails'})
```

My configuration is loaded from an object called ProductionConfig:

```
class Config(object):
    '''Default configuration object.'''
    DEBUG = False
    TESTING = False
    PORT = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))

class ProductionConfig(Config):
    '''Configuration object specific to production environments.'''
    REDIS_URL = os.environ.get('REDISTOGO_URL')
    if REDIS_URL:
        url = urlparse.urlparse(REDIS_URL)
        REDIS_HOST = url.hostname
        REDIS_PORT = url.port
        REDIS_PASSWORD = url.password

    MONGOLAB_URI = os.environ.get('MONGOLAB_URI')
    if MONGOLAB_URI:
        url = urlparse.urlparse(MONGOLAB_URI)
        MONGODB_USER = url.username
        MONGODB_PASSWORD = url.password
        MONGODB_HOST = url.hostname
        MONGODB_PORT = url.port
        MONGODB_DB = url.path[1:]
```

Here is the error I keep getting:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: database error: unauthorized db:MONGODB_DB lock type:-1 client:10.117.107.165
```

The OperationFailure exception is raised by PyMongo's [_unpack_response](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/master/pymongo/helpers.py#L78) function in the helpers.py file, specifically lines 103 and 104.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks wrong to me:

```
db = connection['MONGODB_DB']
```

Perhaps you want

```
db = connection[config['MONGODB_DB']]
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed actually! `db = connection['MONGODB_DB']` should have been `db = connection[f.config['MONGODB_DB']]`. Thanks. :)